# How to do a background grid color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am creating an app and I want to do a background like in this picture:

[image]

How can I do it by the easiest way ?

Comment: What did you try so far? What does it have to do with animation? We don't do your work on this site, we *help* you, to do *your own work*. So you need to tell us what you did so far and what the exact problem is where you are stuck so we can help with that.

Comment: I am searching the best way to do this !
I tried with gridview but I am searching to do this in an easier way

Comment: There is no one best way to do this. Nothing in computing has the one best way for everybody. A grid might need less resources and more coding work. A prepainted picture might use more resources, scales slightly worse but is easier to implement. If we don't know why you think your try is not good enough, nobody will be able to help you. That is why we need to see what you did and what you want to improve about it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is not a code writing service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it use CustomPaint

For Example

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    getHttp();
//
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: CustomPaint(
        painter: BacgroundPaint(),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BacgroundPaint extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final height = size.height;
    final width = size.width;
    final paint = Paint();

    Path mainBackground = Path();
    mainBackground.addRect(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, width, height));
    paint.color = Colors.teal;

    final heightLine = height ~/ 20; // your Horizontal line
    final widthLine = (width ~/ 10); // your Vertical line

    for(int i = 1 ; i < height ; i++){
      if(i % heightLine == 0){
         Path linePath = Path();
         linePath.addRect(Rect.fromLTRB(0, i.toDouble(), width, (i+2).toDouble()));
         canvas.drawPath(linePath, paint);
      }
    }
    for(int i = 1 ; i < width ; i++){
      if(i % widthLine == 0){
        Path linePath = Path();
        linePath.addRect(Rect.fromLTRB(i.toDouble(), 0 , (i+2).toDouble(), height));
        canvas.drawPath(linePath, paint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate != this;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Here is my simple approach to draw grid lines

```
  _drawGridLines({double space = 30, Color color = Colors.red, Widget child}) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        double width = constraints.maxWidth;
        double height = constraints.maxHeight;
        var h = Container(width: 2, height: height, color: color);
        var v = Container(width: width, height: 2, color: color);
        return Stack(children: <Widget>[
          ...List.generate((width / space).round(), (index) => Positioned(left: index * space, child: h)),
          ...List.generate((height / space).round(), (index) => Positioned(top: index * space, child: v)),
          if(child != null) child,
        ]);
      },
    );
  }
```

**Usage**

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(body: _drawGridLines()),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a container in your material app like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("path/image.format"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
    child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Whatever you draw upon this layout should have a transparent backgroundColor else it will not be visible. Hope it works!

Comment: The more simple way is to use the Gridpaper Widget ;) :  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridPaper-class.html . For example, simply wrap you container with GridPaper() and define subdivisions, interval, color. Hope it helps